# Unique random int from sequence

Tags: java, database, uniqueidentifier

i am trying to create unique random identifier strategy. I do not want to store or query all ids that were already used, I'd like to use as a source of uniquesness a sequence generating numbers 0 -> Integer.MAX_VALUE. The thing I am thing that I am missing is a function that will project each number from the sequence to another in the same range.

Can you please point to some fast bijection function for this? (Prefferably in Java).

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want a simple counter? And what do you mean with this: *"The thing I am thing that I am missing is a function that will project each number from the sequence to another in the same range. "*?

Comment: Why stop at `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Why not stop at Long.MAX_VALUE'? Are you targeting a particular DB? Why not let the DB handle this?

Comment: Tom: i want a counter that generates "random" output. It must not be possible to easily guess the order or number of identifiers that were already generated.

Comment: For which purpose you want your identifiers to be "random"? Why autoincrementing numbers don't satisfy you? Is it for hash table implementation or for security reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to produce "unguessable" random numbers, you can take [`SecureRandom.nextLong()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) and append it with `System.nanoTime()`. The nanoTime part is easier to guess, but will not repeat after very short period of time. The nextLong part may repeat in future, but it's very hard to guess.

Note that if you have any determenistic bijection function hardcoded in your application and somebody will be able to obtain and reverse it (get sources, decompile class files, etc.), then your IDs will be compromised: it would be quite easy to find next/previous numbers by given one.